# Issue when installing python-package virtualenvwrappe

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, pip

I am new to Linux and Raspberry Pi, so I am sorry if this is a trivial question or if I did not mention some important information.

To my problem:

I have a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and want to install OpenCV on it. For this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Within this tutorial, it is also recommended to use virtual environments for programming in Python. Therefore, the packages `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` are installed. However, once I enter the command `sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Package'stevedore' requires a different Python: 3.5.3 not in '>=3.6'
```

The first thing I tried to solve the problem was to upgrade Python to a higher version. So now the command `python3 --version' returns '3.6.9`. However, this did not help and the error persisted. I also tried using pip3 within the command but then I get the following message: "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the `ssl` module in Python is not available." which then led to a different error. I also tried downloading the package directly from https://www.piwheels.org/ but without success.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Stretch includes 3.5, I don't know how you got 3.6. The current *Raspberry Pi OS* (Buster) includes 3.7. Regardless pip will install in 2.7. You should use pip3

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. This is my bad as I did not explain correctly. 
I had the fresh installation but then upgraded Python to version 3.6.9. So when I query the version with 'python --version' it shows me '3.6.9'.
I did this after I got the error the first time because I thought it could resolve the issue which it did not. 
Using pip3 leads to the following issue: 'pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. '
I hope this helps.

Comment: DO NOT include details in Comments - edit your question. If python -V returns anything other than 2.7 you have broken something.

Comment: I am sorry for that, it is the first time I use this website and ask a question. I now edited the question. And I meant querying 'python3 --version'. But I changed it correctly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did this :

***pi@ai-pi:~ $*** sudo su

***root@ai-pi:/home/pi#*** cd /usr/src

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src#*** wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src#*** tar -xf Python-3.7.0.tgz

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src#*** apt-get update

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src#*** apt-get install -y build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src#*** cd Python-3.7.0

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src/Python-3.7.0#***./configure --enable-optimizations

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src/Python-3.7.0#*** make altinstall

***root@ai-pi:/usr/src/Python-3.7.0#*** ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3

***$*** wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

***$*** sudo python3 get-pip.py

***$*** sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

And it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference an older version of stevedore

1.29 is the version of stevedore from around the time the article was written.

```
sudo pip install stevedore==1.29.0
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

worked for me.